# React-Table (v8) with ColumnMeta properties does not allow added meta properties to be used in columndefs

Tags: reactjs, react-table

It seems that React-Table (v8) with ColumnMeta properties  does allow typescript access to  the added properties in columndefs - am I missing something. The extra property is added as added via docs as:

````
  interface ColumnMeta<TData extends RowData, TValue> {
     enableColumnEdit:boolean
  }
}  ```


Later I try to define default columns using:
    
  ```const defaultColumns: (ColumnDef<Task>)[] = [
              {
                accessorKey: 'id' ,
             cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
                header: () => <span>id</span>,
                footer: (props) => props.column.id,    
                minSize: 20,
             enableColumnEdit:false,
            },]
````

Typescript reports error that the enableColumnEdit property does not exist.

I thought the intent and purpose was the meta values get merged into the column properties, but that does not seem to be happening.   Am I missing something? The docs do tell you how to define meta, but I cannot find an example that actually uses the resulting meta, so cannot spot what I am doing wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be nesting `enableColumnEdit` inside a property called `meta`:

```
const defaultColumns: (ColumnDef<Task>)[] = [
   {
      accessorKey: 'id' ,
      cell: (info) => info.getValue(),
      header: () => <span>id</span>,
      footer: (props) => props.column.id,    
      minSize: 20,
      meta: {
         enableColumnEdit: false,
      }
   }
];
```

Comment: Thanks Matt,  Your answer with meta as an object is correct.  It took a little while to find how to access the meta value during the cell render,    For those that wish to follow the cell renderer was extended to access the meta property using, 
  
    const thisColumnDef = table.getColumn(id).columnDef
    const canEdit = thisColumnDef.meta?.enableColumnEdit ?? false
  ```

Comment: I have tried this also but typescript keeps complaining:
{cell.column.columnDef.meta?.icon ?? ''}  Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'ColumnMeta<any, unknown>'
 I have assigned an object to the meta property that contains an icon... Am i missing something here?

I am using @tanstack/svelte-table.

Comment: definition of `ColumnMeta` interface does not allow any values there :/
`export interface ColumnMeta<TData extends RowData, TValue> {}`

Comment: @RonaldBrinkerink you need to redefine the interface: `declare module '@tanstack/table-core/build/lib/types' { export interface ColumnMeta<TData extends RowData, TValue> { /* your def here */ } }`